# How to calculate charges based on timer in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an android app that does arithmetic calculation while the timer is running. How can I do it?

This is the calculation class

```
 public class CalculateCharges {

    private Double total = 0.0;
    private long secs,mins,hrs;

    public Double calculateTotal(long hours, long mins) {

        if (mins < 1) {
            return total = 0.05;
        }

        if (mins == 1 || (mins > 1 && mins < 2)) {
            return total = total + 0.25;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the MainActivity class

```
public void startClick (View view) {
    showStopButton();

    if (stopped) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime;
    }
    else {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
    mHandler.postDelayed(startTimer, 0);
}
```

This is the update timer

```
private void updateTimer (float time) {
    secs = (long)(time/1000);
    mins = (long)((time/1000)/60);
    hrs = (long)(((time/1000)/60)/60);

    /* Convert the seconds to String * and format to ensure it has * a leading zero when required */

    secs = secs % 60;
    seconds = String.valueOf(secs);

    if (secs == 0) {
        seconds = "00";
    }

    if (secs < 10 && secs > 0) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    /* Convert the minutes to String and format the String */

    mins = mins % 60;
    minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

    if (mins == 0) {
        minutes = "00";
    }

    if (mins < 10 && mins > 0) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    /* Convert the hours to String and format the String */

    hours = String.valueOf(hrs);

    if (hrs == 0) {
        hours = "00";
    }

    if (hrs < 10 && hrs > 0) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer)).setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

    Double total = calc.calculateTotal(hrs, mins);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayTotal)).setText(total.toString());

}
```

This is the runnable

```
private Runnable startTimer = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        updateTimer(elapsedTime);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

When I run the code, it just shows $0.05 but it won't update after 1 minute.

If you can help me solve this or guide me on how to solve this, it would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here:

```
if (mins == 1 || (mins > 1 && mins < 2)) {
        return total = total + 0.25;
}
```

The minutes cannot be greater than 1 and less than 2 while being a `long`. It is not a `double` or `float`.

Anyway, change your class to:

```
public class CalculateCharges {

    private Double total = 0.0;
    private long secs,mins,hrs;

    public Double calculateTotal(long hours, long mins) {

        if (mins < 1) {
            total = 0.05;
        } else if (mins == 1) {
            total = total + 0.25;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't solve mate, however it gave me an idea which really helped.